# Code Contracts: How do I state in a post-condition that a field/property's value has not changed?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts, design-by-contract

I'll best just show with a code example what I would like to accomplish?

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeProperty;

    public void SomeOperation()
    {
        Contract.Ensures( "SomeProperty's value has not changed." );
                     //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                     //    How can I write this post-condition?
    }
};
```

(The string passed to `Contract.Ensures()` is of course just a placeholder for the real post-condition expression.)

How can I do this? Would `Contract.OldValue<>()` be of any use here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Contract.OldValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412857(VS.100).aspx) should be enough:

```
Contract.Ensures(this.SomeProperty == Contract.OldValue(this.SomePropety));
```